# Add new function to parent window from same-domain iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

From a same domain iframe I want to create a new function and append it to the parent window and then invoke that function from either the iframe or the parent. Something like this.

```
parent.myFunction = function(){ ... }; myfunction;
```

is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Did you test it ? You were almost there.

Comment: I did but I think there was a syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do almost exactly what you did

```
parent.myFunction = function(){ ... };
parent.myfunction(); // calling the function in parent window
```

And from the parent window, you'll be able to do simply

```
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

to invoke function from child window use `parent.myfunction();`

```
parent.myFunction = function(){ ... }; parent.myfunction();
```